# Solving multivariate function using Newton's method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, newton-raphson

I'm working on the equation $yx = e^{x+y}$. I'm trying to approximate the roots using Newton's method (solving for y), but I can't figure it out and examples only offer system of equations. I'm not given any initial values or whatsoever. Anyone can help me out? I just don't see how I can even set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the equation $$yx = e^{x+y}$$ is given as 
$$y=-W\left(-\frac{e^x}{x}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Have a look at the *"numerical evaluation"* section to see Newton method.

Comment: Suppose I add the condition that I only want positive values for x and y. Would that be a condition I can add to use Newton’s method?